# Does changing your reach provoke opportunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, unearthed-arcana, reach, mystic

If a Mystic focusing on *Giant Growth* changes their reach, does it provoke opportunity attacks?

---

#### Relevant rules

**PHB p195**

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you
> can see moves out of your reach.

**PHB 190**

> A reaction is an instant response to a trigger of some kind, which can occur **on your turn** or on someone else's.

This implies that you can make opportunity attacks on your turn.

For the [**UA Mystic (V3)**](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/mystic-class) class, the discipline *Giant Growth* states:

> While focused on this discipline, your reach increases by 5 feet.

And the class feature *Psychic Focus* says:

> You can focus psionic energy on one of your psionic disciplines to draw ongoing benefits from it. As a bonus action, you can choose one of your psionic disciplines to gain its psychic focus benefit, which is detailed in that discipline's description. The benefit lasts until you are incapacitated or until you use another bonus action to choose a different focus benefit.

---

#### Question

My understanding of this is that, assuming I am focusing on *Giant Growth* and have a reach of 10', if I use my bonus action to focus on something else, my reach reduces to 5' and all creatures that are further than 5' away from me and less than 10' provoke opportunity attacks. Is there any reason that this would not be the case?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As you also quote:

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you
>   can see moves out of your reach.

None of the creatures have **moved** if your reach changes, therefore they do not provoke Opportunity Attacks.

This reading is also supported by the rest of the OA rules that state that forced movement does not provoke. The target has to use his movevement.

Comment: Also, might be worth pointing out that droping a reach weapon like a Glaive wouldn't magically allow you to punch someone 10 feet away.